# Give access to User.ProfileId without "View Profile and Configuration" permission

Tags: visual-workflow, profile, sobject, access

I created a flow that has to access the profileId of Order.Owner:

[image]

But when the user runs the flow, the following error occurs:
***"An error occurred: The flow failed to access the value for GetOrderRecord.Owner:User.Profile.Id because the field is not available to the running user."***

I saw that the user's profile can't access "Profile" SObject. I'm trying to give access to it, but there are no options like other objects (see the picture bellow).
What could I do?
[image]

Comment: Can you try adding "Manage User" permission on permission set

Comment: is flow running in system context or user context? see [help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5)

Comment: @cropredy I changed it to system context and it worked! But is there a solution to give access to the user's profile to "Profile" SObject?

Comment: Have you tried the above permission?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, it has only the tab view options about "Profile" sobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce [defaults the execution context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) based on the type of flow

- User
- System w/ sharing
- System w/o sharing

User context enforces CRUD, FLS and sharing (i.e. record visibility). System context ignores FLS and CRUD and you can choose to include w/ or w/o sharing

You can change the default by using the [Advanced setting](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_system_mode.htm&type=5) for the Flow.

For your use case, it might be safer to switch the context to System rather than granting that user via a permission set `Manage Users` permission which would open up access to the `Profile` for a given `OwnerId`